# How can I show the horizontal scrollbar on a kendo ui grid after filtering?

Tags: filter, grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI grid with many columns.  Columns that overflow can be viewed by scrolling horizontally. However, if you

1) scroll to a column that is not initially displayed and

2) filter on that column such that no rows match the filter criteria

the grid will no longer allow scrolling horizontally. The column that had the filter applied cannot be cleared.

How can I show the horizontal scrollbar after such filtering?

Here's a jsfiddle where you can see the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/9sxkG/1/

Here's the code:

```js
var dataItem = {};
var columns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dataItem['col' + i] = i;
    columns.push( {
        field: 'col' + i,
        width: 80,
        filterable: true,
        type: 'number'
    } );
}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable:true,
    columns: columns,
    filterable: true,
    dataSource: [dataItem]
});
```

For example, go to column 18 and filter on equal to 20 to see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Trey Gramman approach of adding a *clear filter* button:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    columns   : columns,
    filterable: true,
    toolbar   : [
        {
            name      : "clean_filter",
            imageClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel-clear",
            text      : "clean filter"
        }
    ],
    dataSource: [dataItem]
});

$(".k-grid-clean_filter", "#grid").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
});
```

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sxkG/3/).

It does not solve the question of scrolling headers but at least allows you continue (if nothing better is found).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it adding a empty row to the grid.
Code:

```js
var dataItem = {};
var columns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  dataItem['col' + i] = i;
  columns.push( {
    field: 'col' + i,
    width: 80,
      filterable: true,
      type: 'number'
  } );
}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable:true,
    columns: columns,
    filterable: true,
    dataSource: [dataItem],
    dataBound: function(e) {  
        if(this.dataSource.view().length == 0) {
             var colspan = this.content.find("table col").length;
             this.content.find("table").append("<tr><td colspan=" + colspan + "></td></tr>");
        }
        $("#grid").find(".k-grid-footer-wrap").scrollLeft($("#grid").find(".k-grid-content").scrollLeft());        
        this.content.bind('scroll', function () {
            $("#grid").find(".k-grid-footer-wrap").scrollLeft(this.scrollLeft);
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting delima.  I think your simplest answer is to add a button next to the grid to 'refresh' the Grid.  The following javascript will cause the refresh.

```
function LoadAllPositions() {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to update my jsfiddle with your idea and the horizontal scroll bar doesn't seem to reappear. So, column x through column n (where x is the last visible column on your display when fully scrolled left and n (is the last column of the grid) are  still not accessible to clear the filter. Or are you suggesting to reload the original data? If the former, could you please update/fork the fiddle to demonstrate this working? If the latter, then I think that the user experience would be fairly poor to require them to take this action.

Comment: But I suppose it's lesser of two evils.